# How to create proper filters with Flask and PyMongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

My first post here :)

I'm using Flask and PyMongo for my site and I want the user to have an ability to filter database results. To start simple:

Basic filter would return results based on the price argument. If the price is None then I want to return all the results.

From MongoDB docs:

> The $or operator performs a logical OR operation on an array of two or more expressions and selects the documents that satisfy at least one of the expressions

```py
   price = request.args.get('price')
   if price:
       price = int(price)

   posts = db.collection.find({ '$or' : [
                                {'price' : {'$lt' : price }},
                                {'price' : {'$ne' : None }}
                                ]
                              })
```

My idea was that if the price is not an integer (None) that the $or operator wouldn't satisfy first expression and move to the second one returning all that are not equal to None. However this doesn't really work and I can't figure any other way to display 'all' results when the argument is not passed or when it is wrong.

Also a bit borader questions - what if I want to have multiple filters? Should I create one big query for the database using $and operator and manipulate variable values in order to get the desired result? Or is there a better way? The only thing I thought about was a route for each filter but this doesn't sound like something that would work. Any suggestions are welcome! Thank you!

Comment: What results do you get and what do you mean "doesn't really work"?

Comment: When I just enter my host without specifying any parameter I get all the results. When I pass the ?price=500 I also get all the results.

Comment: Then the `$or` is working as designed - returning all the documents that satisfy any one of the conditions. It is checking that the value of price in the document is not None (nothing to do with the entered price). So you could select all when no price is entered and just use the filter when a price is entered.

Comment: And how would I do that exactly? You mean by creating the condition and checking if price has any value - if so then using the filter, if not then skipping it? What if I have multiple filters? Should I create every combination of if statements for each filter? Doesn't sound like elegant solution. Perhaps you had something else in mind and I don't follow.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32303483/user-input-for-a-mongodb-search) provide any insight for dynamically generating the query - it appears to be similar to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

For multiple filters:

```
filter = {}
if price is not None: filter['price'] = {'$lt' : price }
if quantity is not None: filter['quantity'] = {'$lt' : quantity }
if volume is not None: filter['volume'] = {'$lt' : volume }

posts = db.testcollection.find(filter)
```

**ORIGNAL:**

Try this to save yourself going slightly mad in the boolean logic world:

```
if price is None:
    filter = {}
else:
    filter = {'price' : {'$lt' : price }}

posts = db.collection.find(filter)
```

Comment: This works fine if there is only one filter. How about multiple ones? I've got like 10 categories and would like to filter the results according to users choice. If done this way it would be very long, complicated and not really elegant solution.

Comment: This works for me! Didn't know that you can do this that way. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass an array from a front end (using query parameters) you can use the $in parameter for mongodb:
URL Parameters sent in array as JSON object:

`/read?job_type%5B%5D=Full%20Time&job_type%5B%5D=Part%20Time&country%5B%5D=Germany&country%5B%5D=China`

```
@app.route("/read", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def read():
    job_type = request.args.getlist('job_type[]')
    country = request.args.getlist('country[]')
    filter = {}
    if len(job_type) > 0: filter['job_type'] = {'$in': job_type}
    if len(country) > 0:  filter['country'] = {'$in': country}
    jobs = db_operations.find(filter)
```